# AAPT2 error when building an Android app using gradle on Termux

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, termux

I [installed](https://hax4us.github.io/2021-11-22-install-android-sdk-in-termux/) Android SDK in Termux. I've got a simple [project](https://github.com/InnovAnon-Inc/ContactQR). I got it to compile manually using [these](https://authmane512.medium.com/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676) instructions, so I proceeded with adding a contact picker using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/contact-picker-in-android/) tutorial, which uses androidx dependencies, so now I am trying to compile with gradle, so it manages the dependencies. I added gradle configs as per the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/build#groovy).

I run:

```bash
./gradlew clean build
```

And I get this error:

```bash
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preFreeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeFreeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileFreeDebug
> Task :app:generateFreeDebugResValues
> Task :app:checkFreeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:mapFreeDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateFreeDebugResources
> Task :app:packageFreeDebugResources
> Task :app:createFreeDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksFreeDebug
> Task :app:parseFreeDebugLocalResources
> Task :app:processFreeDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:mergeFreeDebugResources
> Task :app:processFreeDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeFreeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileFreeDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateFreeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeFreeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressFreeDebugAssets
> Task :app:desugarFreeDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:processFreeDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkFreeDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:processFreeDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeLibDexFreeDebug
AAPT2 aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9e8f852fb62449ec2d4f2489de052d41/transformed/aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux/aapt2[18]: syntax error: unexpected ')'
AAPT2 aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9e8f852fb62449ec2d4f2489de052d41/transformed/aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux/aapt2[18]: syntax error: unexpected ')'
> Task :app:processFreeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeFreeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:mergeExtDexFreeDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processFreeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:freeDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2c78914f4e8a8669078cd47dc84a7b77/transformed/appcompat-1.6.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

It's basically pulling in it's own version of aapt2 instead of the one installed on the system and then complaining about a closing parenthesis:

```bash
Unexpected error output: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9e8f852fb62449ec2d4f2489de052d41/transformed/aapt2-8.0.0-9289358-linux/aapt2[18]: syntax error: unexpected ')'
```

The developer/maintainer of the Termux aapt2 package said I must somehow be using libraries or executables for the wrong architecture.

On my GitHub workflow, this part seems to work okay, but instead I get a different error complaining about resources:

```bash
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preFreeReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateFreeReleaseResValues
> Task :app:mapFreeReleaseSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateFreeReleaseResources
> Task :app:createFreeReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksFreeRelease
> Task :app:mergeFreeReleaseResources
> Task :app:processFreeReleaseMainManifest
> Task :app:processFreeReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processApplicationManifestFreeReleaseForBundle
> Task :app:mergeFreeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:compileFreeReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateFreeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeFreeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:bundleFreeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleFreeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable
   > Android resource linking failed
> Task :app:checkFreeReleaseDuplicateClasses
12 actionable tasks: 12 executed
     /home/runner/work/ContactQR/ContactQR/app/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/freeRelease/AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.innovanon.contactqr.free:string/app_name) not found.
     /home/runner/work/ContactQR/ContactQR/app/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/freeRelease/AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.innovanon.contactqr.free:style/AppTheme) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

Did I incorrectly setup my build environment or is my project incorrectly configured?

Comment: I met the same error. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `res` folder in `app/src/main`, so the project structure might something like this.

```
<project-name>
├─ app/
│  ├─src
│     ├─ main
│         ├─ <package-name>
│         ├─ res
│             ├─ <resources>
│  <gradle...etc.>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met similar error when upgrading compileSdk and targetSdkVersion to 34 and a few dependencies.
In my experience, I compared with some other project which was build OK after upgrading SDK 34 etc. and find the difference in build.gradle(Project:xxxx):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

The project having this error is 4.3.10. I upgrade it to 4.3.15 and the build OK!